# $_GET returns NULL when it's already not empty

Tags: php, get

I have a link like this: `http://localhost/edit.php?id=0`

But, When I try to take the value like this: `$id = $_GET['id'];`

It returns `null`. Why it's happening? My code is like this:

```
<?php
public function loadEdit($hconn) {
    if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        if ($this->isNumber($id) != true && !($id > 0)) {
            echo $id;
            header("Location: /goods.php");
        } else {
            //header("Location: /goods.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {` which will evaluate to false if `$_GET['id']` has a value/string of zero.

Try using this instead:

`if (isset($_GET['id'])) {`

Comment: I preferred `if ($_GET['id'] !== null) {`

Comment: Doing this will result in PHP notice/errors being thrown if `$_GET['id']` does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure that this, all my projects are using `!== null` and work fine. Please, can you test and tell me. Thank for all in advances.

Comment: I am certain. If you access an array key that does not exist, it will cause a notice/error.

Comment: Can you add me at your gmail chat? my username is jramoscarmenates@gmail.com Thanks. I very interesting in learning. I'm development php, and nodejs.

Comment: @lan: You have reason, I confused `!==` with `array_key_exists`. I'm very so sorry for this. I used `!==` by variables.

Comment: still returns null :(

Comment: When I post that form, the get value gets null. I don't know why.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I posted to the action="/edit.php", I should post to the nothing, like action="".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use:

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {
```